# What does 'both' mean in this case?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Probably, if I had lately left a good home and kind parents, this would have been the hour when I should most keenly have regretted the separation; that wind would then have saddened my heart; this obscure chaos would have disturbed my peace: as it was, I derived from **both** a strange excitement, and reckless and feverish, I wished the wind to howl more wildly, the gloom to deepen to darkness, and the confusion to rise to clamour.
>   (Jane Eyre)

What does *both* indicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Both** refers to **that wind** and to **this obscure chaos**, which is confirmed by the end of the quotation: "I wished **the wind** to howl more wildly, the gloom to deepen to darkness, and **the confusion** to rise to clamour".